# How to find the location of the configuration file passed as argument to Python script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, config, configuration-files

I think the title of the question is descriptive enough.

How can one find the location of the configuration file which is passed as an argument to a python script.

I would like to create a backup of the config file but copying it to another location.

Comment: Isn't the argument the location of the config?

Comment: Can post and example of how you supply this argument to your script on the command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join current working folder to the argument path to get an absolute path.

```
import os
import sys

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    full_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), sys.argv[1])
    print(full_path)
```

Comment: but this will not work for a config file which is not in the same directory with the script, will it?

Comment: It will. If you provide an absolute path, the result is the absolute path, whereas if you provide a relative path, it is relative to the current folder.